# Ciphertext that looks like language

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Are there any ciphers that produce interesting, or visual ciphertexts?

Most ciphers just produce crazy strings, intended to maximize entropy, but could a ciphertext be language-like?

I know it's a funny question, and it doesn't need to be perfectly secure, but I think it's an interesting problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. http://crypto.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask.

Comment: For sure, you just need infinite cipher monkeys encrypting an infinite number of plaintexts.

Comment: In a first step you use standard encryption to produce random looking bytes. Transforming those into something that looks like language is independent from encryption.

Answer (score 2):

Words of most languages are redundant which is contrary to the purpose of encryption. But you can combine encryption with steganography and hide the result of encryption in some text.

Comment: I think I broke *your* code: the first letter of the three-letter words in your answer form the hidden message "at by cat".

Comment: so, **text+key -> cipher**,
 then **cipher+stenography -> nice_cipher** 

 ..but wouldn't you need to know that if the key was correct, not to do the stenography step?
thanks

Comment: @spencercooly I don't understand your question, sorry. You wanted an encrypted data to look like a valid text in some language. This is done with help of steganography.